# Adding custom field to the subject line in a opensssl X509 certificate via command line

Tags: shell, openssl, ssl, certificates

I am attempting to generate a CSR for a certificate and wish to include a unique id as part of the certificate subject line. this information shall be used by the TLS client for some purpose after the certificate is validated (via normal TLS validation method) and the connection is established.

I am using a script to generate the CSR automatically and I don't have the option to modify the openssl config file present in the system.
I understand that there is a option to generate a temporary ssl config for this purpose where I can specify additional attributes and values into it. But for simplicity I am attempting to avoid it untill I absolutely have to use it.

I am trying the following command but geting a warning mesaage as follows:

```
$ openssl req -key abc.pem -new -out abc.csr -subj "/CN=myhostname.mydomain.com/uuid=a1b2c3d4e5f6"
req: Skipping unknown attribute "uuid"
```

Is there a way to pass the UUID via command line?
If not, is the only other alternative is to use a temp config file?

Comment: What's the definition of `uuid`?  There's a `UID` defined in OpenSSL, but no `uuid`.

Comment: @ garethTheRed No, the UUID is a custom information, nothing related to openSSL. It is passed to my certificate generation script as an argument wich needs to be included in the subject line. –

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSL doesn't know what `uuid` means, and therefore cannot add it to the request.

You can define new attributes in the `openssl.cnf` file and use that for all requests of this type.

The `openssl.cnf` file should (and may already have) a line that begins `oid_section =`.  This points to a section where you can define your new attributes.

```
oid_section = new_oids
.
.
[ new_oids ]
uuid = 1.3.6.1.4.1.32473.123
```

The number after `uuid` is the Object IDentifier (OID).  An OID is a globally unique ID number which is allocated to this attribute.  They have been defined for the common attributes (such as CommonName and Organization) but if you're using custom attributes you need to define them here so that OpenSSL understands.

The example above uses an enterprise OID arc predefined for example documentation (1.3.6.1.4.1.32473) with a new node of of 123 appended.  You shouldn't use the example arc any more than you should use example.com or example.org for domain names outside of documents.

You can [register for a new enterprise number](https://pen.iana.org/pen/PenApplication.page) for free and create your own set of OIDs.  Any nodes added to the top-level registered OID will be unique and under your control.

Comment: By doing the above, will the command I used in the question work? i.e. the uuid would get added to the subject line? So, if I add a new attribute to the cofiguration file in the server and generate the certificate withe the added information. On the client side, to extract the same information from the certificate, I would need to add the same details to the config file as well, right? Or that is not necessary?

Comment: Yes, to the 1st question - try it first with the example OID, then register your own for production.  No to the 2nd, unless you're using the OpenSSL command line tools for the client too.